# Android:Why not use TYPE_GRAVITY data in getRotationMatrix(float[] R, float[] I, float[] gravity, float[] geomagnetic)?

Tags: android, android-sensors, sensormanager

**gravity** is an array of 3 floats containing the gravity vector expressed in the device's coordinate. You can simply use the values returned by a SensorEvent of a Sensor of type TYPE_ACCELEROMETER. This is noted in SensorManager.getRotationMatrix, but I want to know why not use values of TYPE_GRAVITY ? I think it will be better than using TYPE_ACCELEROMETER.because ACCELEROMETER = GRAVIDY - LINEAR_ACCELEROMETER, ACCELEROMETER won't point to the earth when moving.

Answer (score 0):

The three sensors Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER, Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY and Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION are related by the equation

```
"Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER" =  "Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY" + "Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION"
```

If you register for updates for all three, what you find is that Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER always arrives first, followed by Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY and Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION, and that the values always satisfy that equation. Internally, Android is using filtering, and in particular a Kalman filter, to separate the two.

A low pass filter is a simple way of doing something similar. However, a lot of thought will have gone into the Android mechanism, so I'm sure that if a low pass filter was better, then Android would have implemented that.

Comment: thanks for your answer.but it seems that doesn't meet my question.